# Notepdat Ctrl + Tab, scroll to the start of the text when return

Tags: plugins, notepad++

For a few month Ctrl + Tab has strange behavior.
At first moment I am here:[image]

When I  Ctrl + Tab(or by the mouse) to other document, and after that return to source document, I see that the cursor has moved to the top of the document
[image]

Note my plagin manager list:
[image]

What is the situation here? Before, everything was fine, maybe someone faced a similar situation? After reinstalling the situation has not changed

Comment: But after some time all work good. Cursor takes fixed position after Tab scrolls. Will give additional information here.

Comment: When I change Syntaxis from default to, f. e., XML, then Ctrl+ Tab works fine